# ios APP icon not showing correctly when having border

Tags: ios7, icons, itunes

Hi I have app icon which has a border in it. Now the problem is that it is not displaying it correctly in the iTunes. I have also attached the screenshot of it. Please let me know what wrong am  I doing. The icon being displayed is just a sample from the other app which has the same issue.The image is 512*512 rounded.

[image: second Image![][1]]

Comment: can you post the original picture you uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid rounded corner icon, because Apple applies masks to your icon image for this. Provide a sqaure-ish icon of dimensions 120x120 pixels.

You should avoid rounded corner icon, because 
Hope that helps!

Or if you really want to add border by yourself then you need to follow these guidelines to add border
http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/exact-border-radius-for-ios-icons/